# How to add an user right to access a customized tpl page in Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am new to Drupal and there is an already existing Drupal site I need to maintain. After an user logins, there is a link in menu which connects a node with customized tpl page code. I create a new user but the new user doesn't have the right to access this page. The customized tpl page is a view data page, and even I "edit" it in the page, it doesn't show any option or user right to choose. Where can I set this up? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If page is a view when you edit it under "Basic settings" you have option "Access" where you can set who can see that page by permission or by role. So you have to limit access there and then you have to give your user role you selected if you want to allow him access to that page.

You can i.e. create new role for that purpose, assign it to all users you want to allow accessing that page and then in view, as I described allow access only to that role.